# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'

Tags: python-3.x

Hy, i was trying the [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) module for python. So, i made a code that "encrypts" (i'ts very newbie code) text and save it encrypted, but when i try to save the encrypted bytes i get a "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'". This is very weird, because I look the type of the "encrypted_message" and its a class bytes.

```
def encrypt(paswd, formated_data):
    #generates the salt
    digest = hashes.Hash(hashes.SHA256(), default_backend())
    digest.update(bytes(paswd, "utf-8"))
    salt = digest.finalize()

    kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
        algorithm = hashes.SHA256,
        length = 32,
        salt = salt,
        iterations = 1000000,
        backend = default_backend()
    )
    key = kdf.derive(bytes(paswd, 'utf-8'))
    iv = os.urandom(16)
    encryptor = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CTR(iv), default_backend()).encryptor()
    #untill this line of code everything works fine
    encrypted_msg = encryptor.update(bytes(formated_data, "utf-8")) + encryptor.finalize()

    print(type(encripted_msg)) #this prints <class 'bytes'>

    with open ("./vault/locked.aes", mode = "wb") as f:
        f.writelines( encripted_msg ) #and here i get the error
```

btw, i'm using python 3.6.8

Comment: I think you only need to write the result of `finalize`, so the `update` part should be separated

Comment: Please make a [mre] including complete code and the full error message with traceback.

Comment: Ok, I'll update the post with the full code of the function!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out how to solve this. First of all, the byte class in python storage the data as a list, you could read each byte of data in a loop if you want to. So, the method "writelines()" in a binary data file don't use "\n" to end each line, instead will write each byte in the bytes class variable, just have to transform it into a list and voilá!, the method will read each bite and write it into a file.